# shiny renderDataTable dom option has 'C', <"clear"> and 'T'. What do they mean?

Tags: shiny, dt

I have in shiny/renderDataTable/options

```
dom  = 'RCT<"clear">Blfrtip'
```

What do C, T and <"clear"> signify?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I came across:

-- In the case of ColReorder the letter to activate the feature is R and the ColVis letter is C and TableTools letter is T

-- The TableTools extension has been removed now. Please try the new Buttons extension

-- The ColVis extension has been removed now. Please try the new Buttons extension